# How to get list of values in GROUP_BY clause?

Tags: sql, group-by, sybase

If I have data like this in a table

```
id   data
--   ----
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    4
2    5
3    6
3    4
```

How do I get results like this in a query (on sybase server)?

```
id   data
--   ----
1    1, 2, 3
2    4, 5
3    6, 4
```

Comment: For HiveQL, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444070/how-to-get-array-bag-of-elements-from-hive-group-by-operator.

Comment: BigQuery equivalent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71438848/how-to-get-array-of-values-in-group-by-clause-using-bigquery).

Answer (score 22):

In mysql, use

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(data)
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY id
```

or use your custom separator:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(data SEPARATOR ', ')
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY id
```

**NOTE: The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the `group_concat_max_len` system variable, which has a default value of 1024.**

See [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) for more details and how to change max length.

Comment: link on GROUP_CONCAT has moved: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 16):

I know that in MySQL there is [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and in Sybase I think it's [LIST](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/28523243/-concatenate-string-us.aspx) as stated in another answer:

```
SELECT id, LIST(data||', ')
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 13):

For PostgreSQL, using a similar function [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html).

```
SELECT id, string_agg(data, ',')
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 7):

In PL/SQL you can do it by:

```
SELECT id, LISTAGG(data, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 0) "data"
  FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 6):

In MsSQL you can use a function (Don't know if there is somenthing similar in SyBase)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDataForID]
(
    @ID int
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @output varchar(max)
    select @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + data
    from table
    where ID = @ID

    return @output
END
GO
```

And then:

```
SELECT ID, dbo.GetDataForID(ID) as Data
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 6):

For SQL server:

```
SELECT id, STRING_AGG(data, ',')
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in a straight GROUP BY in plain-vanilla SQL.  You have to use a cursor (or a similar construct) to concatenate the values in each group manually.

- Oracle lets you define a custom aggregator which would do this concatenation in PL/SQL.
- SQL Server lets you define a custom aggregator in .NET which would do this, as well.
- I'm not sure about what options Sybase has for defining custom aggregators, though.

Comment: Sybase lets you define user-defined aggregation functions in C/C++.

Answer (score 3):

For Presto, use [array_agg](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html)

```
SELECT id, array_agg(data)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I think the OP tagged this as a Sybase SQL question

Comment: thanks, I needed this for presto sql and didn't know the equivalent of mysql's group_concat name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to use a cursor (http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/50501;pt=50305)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(data)
FROM   table
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: That's for MySql, not Sybase as specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server:

```
select distinct b.id, data=STUFF((select ',' +convert(varchar,id)
from yourtable a
where a.id=b.id
for xml path ('')),1,1,'')
from yourtable b
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I've tried using the syntax and I no longer have access to an iAnywhere instance, but there was an aggregate function (list) to do such a task.  I cannot confirm if LIST() is still supported.

```
SELECT id,
       LIST(data)
FROM   table
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it is supported in SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.2500)  ("'LIST' is not a recognized built-in function name.")

Answer (score 0):

For SparkSQL (e.g. when querying AWS Athena):

```sql
SELECT id, ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY_AGG(data), ',')
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id;
```