# How do I get one row in the result set out of 2 rows in the table/file without using cursors in Sybase/Perl

Tags: sql, perl, sybase

I have a table T with columns A,B,C & D as below:

```
A  B  C   D  
===============
A1 B1 USD LIBOR  
A1 B2 JPY FIXED  
A2 B3 USD LIBOR  
A2 B4 EUR FIXED  
A3 B5 JPY FIXED  
A3 B6 USD LIBOR
```

1. Table always has 2 rows per "A", with different values of "B".
2. "B" is unique
3. "A" - varchar(10), "B" - varchar(8), "C" - varchar(3), "D" - varchar(5)
4. Validation rules restrict the columns to the below formats -
   "A", "B', "D" - Alphanumeric
   "C" - Alphabetic

I need to extract the below results from the table -

**Result Set 1:**

```
A1 USD LIBOR JPY FIXED  
A2 USD LIBOR EUR FIXED  
A3 JPY FIXED USD LIBOR
```

**Result Set 2:**

```
USD LIBOR JPY FIXED  
USD IBOR  EUR FIXED
```

I wish to avoid using cursors, unless there any other solution.

Can I extract this table into a file and use perl to get the result ?

Please help ...

Comment: Ah, So you don't have the `LIST` function. Doesn't look promising from this question unless you can create user defined functions or aggregates in Sybase? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491566/how-to-get-list-of-values-in-group-by-clause

Comment: The table from which I have to extract has around 100 columns and millions of rows. Apart from using cursors which will not be an optimal solution, I want to try evaluating any other approach you suggest. Even writing a stored procedure or function is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with temporary tables and multiple updates, but I don't think that's going to be very nice in your million line table.

If your data always has 2 rows per "A", with different values of "B" and has predictable sizes (column widths) or format (so you can use special delimators) then something like this might work

`SELECT
   A,
   MIN(B),
   MAX(B),
   right( MIN(B + C), 5),
   right( MIN(B + D), 5),
   right( MAX(B + C), 5),
   right(MAX(B + D), 5)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY A`

Comment: I have tried the above query, but it takes really long and I had to abort.

I have extracted the 4 columns into a temp table "my_table", with index on B to run the query.

Comment: Any suggestions on using temp tables and updates to achieve this.