# How to create a recursive path from sybase-ase db?

Tags: sql, recursion, treeview, sap-ase

I have a problem I've previously solved with other DBMS but can't find a solution to run with Sybase-ASE 15.0. Is this possible with SQL (or Views) without custom StoredProcedures?

Input:

```
ID Name Parent
1  a
2  b    1
3  c    1
4  d    3
```

Output:

```
ID   PATH
1    a
2    a / b
3    a / c
4    a / c / d
```

Comment: found some additional information to the topic [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/HierarchySyBaseMSServer.aspx) (well didn't help me much so far...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer - No.

[How to get list of values in GROUP_BY clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491566/how-to-get-list-of-values-in-group-by-clause)

Comment: looks ok if the recursion has only one level. but I don't see how this works with deeper level recursion.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: this is only supported by Sybase SQL Anywhere, not by the "professional" Adaptive Server Enterprise.

According to the manual, Sybase supports recursive common table expressions.

So the following should work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy_path (id, node_path) AS 
(
  SELECT id, 
         name as node_path
  FROM the_unknown_table
  WHERE id = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT c.id, 
         p.node_path || ' / ' || c.name
  FROM the_unknown_table c
    JOIN hierarchy_path p ON p.id = c.parent_id 
)
SELECT *
FROM path
ORDER BY id
```

Not sure if Sybase uses the standard SQL concatenation operator `||` or something different. As Microsoft is ignoring the standard there, I guess Sybase uses the `+` as well.

Comment: I get `[Error Code: 156, SQL State: ZZZZZ]  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.` Upon my research I found this should be possible with Sybase Anywhere but no hints to Sybase ASE.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I just found this in the Sybase online manual. I didn't realize there was such a difference between ASA and ASE