# Grouping by into a list with activerecord in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to achieve something exactly similar to [How to get list of values in GROUP_BY clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491566/how-to-get-list-of-values-in-group-by-clause) but I need to use active record query interface in rails 4.2.1.

I have only gotten so far.

```
Roles.where(id: 2)
        .select("user_roles.id, user_roles.role, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT roles.group_id SEPARATOR ',') ")
        .group(:role)
```

But this just returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`object with a single entry that has `id` and `role`.

How do I achieve that same with active record without having to pull in all the relationships and manually building such an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Roles.where(id: 2)` already returns the single record. You might instead start with `users` and join `roles` table doing something like this.

```rb
User.
  joins(user_roles: :roles).
  where('roles.id = 2').
  select("user_roles.role, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT roles.group_id SEPARATOR ',') ").
  group(:role)
```

Or, if you have the model for `user_roles`, start with it since you nevertheless do not query anything from `users`.