# How to get array of values in GROUP BY clause using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-cloud-platform, group-by, google-bigquery

This question is modelled on [How to get list of values in GROUP_BY clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491566/how-to-get-list-of-values-in-group-by-clause) - which is a [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase) question, not applicable in BigQuery context.

---

If I have data like this in a table

```
id   data
--   ----
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    4
2    5
3    6
3    4
```

How do I get results like this in a query?

```
id   data
--   ----
1    1, 2, 3
2    4, 5
3    6, 4
```

where `1, 2, 3`, `4, 5` and `6,4` are arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT
  id,
  ARRAY_AGG(data)
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  id
```